# JSON Delet value

Tags: php, json

```
[
    {
        "1":{
        "a":"blablabla",
        "b":"...",
        "c":"..",
        "e":"..."
        },

        "2":{
        "a":"blablabla",
        "b":"...",
        "c":"..",
        "e":"..."
        },

        "3":{
        "a":"blablabla",
        "b":"...",
        "c":"..",
        "e":"..."
        }
    }
]
```

desired result :

```
[
    {
        "1":{
        "a":"blablabla",
        "b":"...",
        "c":"..",
        "e":"..."
        },

        "3":{
        "a":"blablabla",
        "b":"...",
        "c":"..",
        "e":"..."
        }
    }
]
```

hi,

I have a JSON that looks like this, I would like to be able to delete data 2 for example ( with a b c e ), anyone to help me?

I tried a lot of things but it always ends up deleting everything.
I found this which seems to show me the right way, but I can't adapt the code.

```
$data = file_get_contents('teste_data.json');

$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

$arr_index = array();
foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['YOUR KEY'] == SOME VALUE TO COMPARE) {
        $arr_index[] = $key;
    }
}

foreach ($arr_index as $i) {
    unset($json_arr[$i]);
}

$json_arr = array_values($json_arr);

file_put_contents('teste_data.json', json_encode($json_arr));
```

I want to retrieve the value deleted with a GET, but then I don't know how to delete only this one

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result, and the actual code showing the value you tried to compare, not a placeholder

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Data is text...what use is a picture of it? Also please provide the other two pieces of information I requested, as well. Thanks.

Comment: I added little things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array level you are not taking into account

Here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
            [1] => Array (
                    [a] => blablabla
                    [b] => ...
                    [c] => ..
                    [e] => ...
                )
            [2] => Array (
                    [a] => blablabla
                    [b] => hello
                    [c] => ..
                    [e] => ...
                )
            [3] => Array (
                    [a] => blablabla
                    [b] => ...
                    [c] => ..
                    [e] => ...
               )
        )
)
```

So, see comments to find the changes

```
$data = file_get_contents('teste_data.json');

$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

$arr_index = array();
foreach ($json_arr[0] as $key => $value) {
// change         ^^^
    if ($value['b'] == 'SOME VALUE TO COMPARE') {
        $arr_index[] = $key;
    }
}

foreach ($arr_index as $i) {
    unset($json_arr[0][$i]);
    // change      ^^^
}

$json_arr = array_values($json_arr);

file_put_contents('teste_data.json', json_encode($json_arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you changed your desired result, here is the original answer and the modified one:

Remove the key's in the object:

```
<?php

$delete = ["a", "c"];
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('teste_data.json'), true);

foreach ($json[0] as $key => $array) {
    foreach ($delete as $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($value, $array)) {
            unset($array[$value]);
        }
    }
    $json[$key] = $array;
}

file_put_contents('teste_data.json', json_encode(array_values($json)));
```

Remove the keys in the array:

```
<?php

$delete = [1, 3];
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('teste_data.json'), true);

foreach ($delete as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value, $json[0])) {
        unset($json[$value]);
    }
}

file_put_contents('teste_data.json', json_encode(array_values($json)));
```